# intergral of the product of 2 multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

Suppose there are the following relationships between $x,y,w$, $$\begin{align}p(x,y) &= N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)\\ p(x\mid w) &= N(\mu_2,\Sigma_2)\end{align},$$ is it possible to compute $p(y\mid w)$?

Here is what I tried, $$p(y\mid w) = \int p(y\mid x)p(x\mid w)\,dx,$$ which is some sort of Bayesian averaging. But this is tough way for me, since I have to compute the integral of the product of $p(y|x)$ and $p(x|w)$, seems quite hard.

Suppose $$\Sigma_1=\pmatrix{\Sigma_{x} &\Sigma_{xy}\\ \Sigma_{yx} &\Sigma_{y}}, \;\mu_1=\pmatrix{\mu_x\\ \mu_y},$$ and I could get $$p(x) = N(\mu_x,\Sigma_x),$$ then $$p(w) = N(\mu_w,\Sigma_w).$$

My question is, is there existing such a relationship between $y,w$, $$p(y,w)=N(\pmatrix{\mu_y\\ \mu_w},\pmatrix{\Sigma_y &\Sigma_{yw}\\ \Sigma_{wy} &\Sigma_w})\text{ ?}$$ If so, I could compute $p(y\mid w)$ by conditioning on $w$.